# Why does the server application send RST after having gone through SYN->SYN,ACK->ACK?

Tags: sockets, tcp, reset

I have a system with server/client applications. The client will send in socket connection request and the server will accept the socket connection when it's working correctly. However, in some situations (most likely due to ungraceful socket disconnection like system shutdown on client side or crash), the client will not be able to reconnect to the server application. The Wireshark capture shows the client will continue to try to connect; but after going through SYN->SYN,ACK->ACK, the server application will send RST. At this point, sometimes the netstat -an will show the connection is in CLOSE_WAIT state and other times would not show this connection. The capture shows 'Acknowledgment Number: Broken TCP. The ackowledge field is nonzero while the ACK flag is not set.

My questions is why the server application would send this RST?

Comment: If the server sends RST the connection cannot possibly be in CLOSE_WAIT, at either end.

Comment: I guess I can't say for sure that the server application returned the RST. From other articles, the RST should be sent by WinSock? I'm not an expert on this. Can someone answer this? Thanks.